# Matrix library or program using Strings

Tags: matrix

Are there any libraries or programs for matrix operation even if we operate with words for example(in any langauge)?:
[{one,two,three,four}] + [{a,b,c,d}] = [{onea,twob,threec,fourd}]

Comment: Do you mean 'fourd' in the last component of your example? What language are you using? What have you found so far?

Comment: yes, sorry i made a error :)

Comment: Any language, I see there are a lot of libraries with integer or float elements, but no one with text elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have stated vectorial addition in your example, where addition on strings is understood as string concatenation. However, matrices are usually defined on [rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29), in particular on [fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29). I can't imagine how operations on strings, where the addition is concatenation, would define a useful ring. In short, any matrix library will be suitable if the ring type can be defined by the caller, who in turn would have to define a ring for strings, at least the addition. However, using a library just for tasks like the one above seems a bit overdone to me.